# siunitx's \ang errors with variable

Tags: siunitx

When I put a number into a variable and put that variable into `\ang`, I get an `siunitx` error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\def\degreed{129.2234}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int trunc}
\pgfmathprintnumberto{\degreed}{\degree}
\degree\\
\ang{\degree}% Returns:
%! siunitx error: ``restricted-number''
%!
%! Token '$' forbidden in restricted numerical input.

\ang{129}%works
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to put a variable into `\ang`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that `pgf` is returning not just `129` but a more complex piece of data. If you `\show\degree` you get

```
> \degree=macro:
->\pgfutilensuremath {129}.
```

As `siunitx` can round anyway, a simple approach would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\def\degreed{129.2234}
\ang[round-precision = 0, round-mode = places]{\degreed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose that `\begingroup\let\ifmmode\iftrue\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\ang{\degree}}\x` is not really handy. `;-)`

Comment: Not really, but I can't think of anything much better.  Not that I mean't to post this.  I'm still getting used to stackexchange.

Comment: I started this thread in an attempt to resolve a component of a decimal-degrees to degrees-minutes-seconds macro, but it has become too complicated.  I'll move on.  Thanks for the replies.